# Refresh DIV using JQuery w/o need for PHP

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

What i'm looking to do is refresh a few DIV's, but not the whole page. But the catch is my application is with a Industrial Automation Programmable Logic Controller (PLC) with a built in web server. So I do not need to replace the data within the DIV, I just need to refresh it, as the PLC automatically updates the variable, but I need to refresh it on the html page.

Below is the current javascript I was using (from doing some research online). I was unsure if I needed ".load() in there, since all that i have seen load a PHP file in there

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#station_num').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
},1000);
</script>
```

The DIV looks like below:

```
<div id="station_num"><h1>Station :="HMI_Control".StationNum:</h1></div>
```

-the :="HMI_Control".StationNum is a variable from the PLC

So I was able to see the variable flashing (from the fade in/fade out), but the variable wasn't updating on the website (although I can monitor the variable in the PLC and see it change).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can refresh the `DIV` all you want, but if the contents of the `DIV` are not being changed, you're going to see no changes on the DOM. I would suggest a small **AJAX** (or whatever it takes to get the page from the PLC) routine to go grab the new variable and then update the `DIV`.

Comment: But see whats weird, is I can see that variable changing in the PLC, so I know it has changed. It is just not updating, even with the above script. EDIT: AHHH, so even though it changes, I need to retrieve the new variable?

Comment: But without grabbing that data from the PLC to refresh the `:="HMI_Control".StationNum:` variable, what good is fading the div in and out?

Comment: Post your edit.... YES, exactly.

Comment: Makes sense. What would be the easiest way to achieve this, just write some sort of AJAX script to retrieve it? Sorry, i'm new to AJAX/JQuery/Java

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about retrieving PLC data. How do you view it typically? And how do you refresh the `:="HMI_Control".StationNum` variable?

Answer (score 1):

`$('#station_num').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');` won't update anything. It will just hide then show again the same content.

Use this:

```
$('#station_num").html('<h1>Station :="HMI_Control".StationNum:</h1>');
```

This will set again the content of the div.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a shot. I kinda figured the fade in/fade out wouldnt do anything, but i was unsure how to do it since i really dont need a php file to load. I appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval( function()
{
    $('#station_num')
        .fadeOut('slow')
        .html('<h1>Station :="HMI_Control".StationNum:</h1>')
        .fadeIn('slow');
},1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it some thought and give it a shot!